# I cant fix error CS1001: Identifier expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my player attach code for moving platforms:

I'm getting an error CS1001: Identifier expected for some reason ant youtube is not helping me...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttach : MonoBehaviour

{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        function OnTriggerEnter(other.Collider){

            if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
            {
                transform.parent = other.transform;

            }
        }


        function OnTriggerExit(other.Collider){
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "player")
            {
                transform.parent = null;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be as detailed as possible. In which line you get the error? What is the exact error message? Please also read [ask]

Comment: `function OnTriggerEnter(other.Collider)` - that is ***not*** C#-syntax. looks more like you copy-pasted something from the javascript-world? also: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I got a CS1001: Identifier expected error and I watched a Unity tutorial on youtube: https://youtu.be/9KdY4mafG_E?t=347

Answer (score 0):

What you have is `unityscript` which is long **deprecated** and not compatible with `c#`!

And in general do **not** nest MonoBehaviour messages under `Update`! Otherwise the messaging system won't find them and they are never called at all.

Your class should look like

```
public class PlayerAttach : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        // Rather use CompareTag instead of ==
        // the latter fails silently in case of s typo making your debugging live only harder
        if (!other.CompareTag("player")) return;
        
        transform.parent = other.transform;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (!other.CompareTag("player")) return;
        
        transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

Further, a logical question: How exactly do you expect the player object leaving this collider if you make it a parent so whenever the player object moves this object moves along with it?